# Linux Kernel 5.4 get init_task information using sched.h

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am fairly new to Linux Kernel modules. I am trying to write a module which allows me to get some information of the `init_task` process (the initial task with pid = 0). I've written the following code in my module to try and get this information using `sched.h`

```
#include <linux/sched.h>


void init_task_info(void) {
    struct task_struct *task;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
    printk(KERN_INFO "init_task state: %s\n", task->state);
}
```

No matter what I try I get a segmentation fault and am unable to access the `init_task` process. I have also tried `find_task_by_vpid`. Any help on what I am doing wrong would be very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean, but as far as I am aware, the first process, traditionally "init", has PID 1, not 0.

Comment: In any event, a robust module would be checking each function result for an error indicator before using it, rather than assuming that function calls always succeed.  This is true in userspace, too, but especially important in kernel code, where system stability may be at stake.

Comment: `pid_task()` seems to accept a null pointer as its first parameter (in which case it will return  `NULL`) so it should only be necessary to check the return value of `pid_task()` in this case as a short-cut to also checking the return value of `find_vpid()` is valid.

Comment: @IanAbbott I am not 100% sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, regarding @JohnBollinger's comments, you can get away with only checking that `pid_task()` returns a non-null value. No need to check that `find_vpid()` returns a non-null value in this case unless you want to! As an absolute minimum, you should check the return value of `pid_task()` is non-null before dereferencing it.

Comment: @IanAbbott I see, would you know how I could change my code to not error?

Comment: `if (task == NULL)` `return;` `printk(KERN_INFO "init_task state: %s\n", task->state);`